# pandas rollign window apply function to dataframe slice?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Without indexing and for/while loops, I'd like to apply a function to a rolling window on my dataframe, that returns a row, for what will become a new dataframe (or extra columns on my previous one). The best method I've found so far is the one below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(10), "B": range(10, 20), "C": range(20, 30)})
def foo(window):
    print(window, "\n-------\n")
    return np.array([[1,2,3]])

df[["D", "F", "G"]] = df.rolling(window=2, method="table").apply(foo,engine="numba",  raw=True)
print(df)
```

The problems for me here are:

1. It only works with the `raw` option (i.e. my function gats a `numpy.ndarray` not a dataframe), so I can't reference columsn by their named in the operations of the function being applied.
2. The return value needs to have the same number of columns as my input, while I may need to have many more input columns than output ones.

Is there a default method for this? I know could use a while loop, but this would very messy in my code base, and likely less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how big is your data but you can try [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) and then construct temporary dataframe with `copy=False` (I know, it uses for loop - but the speed might be sufficient):

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

cols = ["A", "B", "C"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(10), "B": range(10, 20), "C": range(20, 30)})

data = [(None, None, None, None)]
for x in sliding_window_view(df.values, window_shape=(2, 3)):
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(x[0], columns=cols, copy=False)

    # compute some dummy values:
    a = df_tmp["A"].sum()
    b = (df_tmp["A"] + df_tmp["B"]).mean()
    c = (df_tmp["C"] - 1).prod()
    d = (df_tmp["B"] * 2).sum()

    data.append((a, b, c, d))

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["D", "E", "F", "G"])], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A   B   C     D     E      F     G
0  0  10  20   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
1  1  11  21   1.0  11.0  380.0  42.0
2  2  12  22   3.0  13.0  420.0  46.0
3  3  13  23   5.0  15.0  462.0  50.0
4  4  14  24   7.0  17.0  506.0  54.0
5  5  15  25   9.0  19.0  552.0  58.0
6  6  16  26  11.0  21.0  600.0  62.0
7  7  17  27  13.0  23.0  650.0  66.0
8  8  18  28  15.0  25.0  702.0  70.0
9  9  19  29  17.0  27.0  756.0  74.0
```